# Strange behavior of the WinDbg debugger when calculating the offset from the nearest resolved function entry

Tags: windbg

I use Windows 7 and WinDbg 6.12.0002.633 X86. I disassemble the rundll32!CallRunDllFunction

function (perhaps this effect is also characteristic of other functions):

```
0:000> uf rundll32!CallRunDllFunction
rundll32!CallRunDllFunction+0x13:
00b0136e ff7518          push    dword ptr [ebp+18h]
00b01371 ff7514          push    dword ptr [ebp+14h]
00b01374 ff7510          push    dword ptr [ebp+10h]
00b01377 ff750c          push    dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]
00b0137a ff5508          call    dword ptr [ebp+8]
00b0137d 8b254850b000    mov     esp,dword ptr [rundll32!s_RunDllStackPointer (00b05048)]
00b01383 61              popad
00b01384 c9              leave
00b01385 c3              ret

rundll32!CallRunDllFunction:
00b01446 55              push    ebp
00b01447 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
00b01449 60              pushad
00b0144a 89254850b000    mov     dword ptr [rundll32!s_RunDllStackPointer (00b05048)],esp
00b01450 b910000000      mov     ecx,10h

rundll32!CallRunDllFunction+0xf:
00b01455 6a00            push    0
00b01457 e2fc            loop    rundll32!CallRunDllFunction+0xf (00b01455)

rundll32!CallRunDllFunction+0x13:
00b01459 e910ffffff      jmp     rundll32!CallRunDllFunction+0x13 (00b0136e)
```

As a result, the value of the symbol rundll32!CallRunDllFunction+0x13 has two values. Based on the first line it is 00b0136e, based on the last line it is 00b01459.
Another command gives the second result:

```
0:000> ?rundll32!CallRunDllFunction+0x13
Evaluate expression: 11539545 = 00b01459
```

At the same time, the following command gives the first value:

```
0:000> u 00b0136e l2
rundll32!CallRunDllFunction+0x13:
00b0136e ff7518          push    dword ptr [ebp+18h]
00b01371 ff7514          push    dword ptr [ebp+14h]
```

I can't understand this debugger behavior. Maybe this is a bug?

Comment: Do not rely on func+offset numbers after optimisation functions are split into chunks and the offsets become redundant  use the resolved address.  136e which is way earlier than start of function not a linear address